# Wordpress user roles who can create posts but cannot see plugins installed for the post tool

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permissions, roles

As I am assigning roles in a Wordpress account such as Editor or Author, who can create posts, they are not able to see or use a plugin installed/integrated in the post tool (for example: Duplicate Post Plugin adds a "Copy" button in the posts section but these user roles don't display it at all). I really want to avoid assigning Admin roles to the these users but I'd like them to be able to use the plugin, naturally. Is there maybe a solution?

I tried all different roles besides Admin and also a few plugins for changing permissions for the different roles but haven't found any yet that achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins may have hooks to override this, but most will just have the required capabilities fixed in their plugin code. No point editing the plugin code directly as it will be overwritten on plugin update.

You could create a new user role with customised capabilities, or you could add the required plugin capability to the existing role, or you could give your user a higher level role. A custom role gives you the most flexibility.

Comment: Yes, thanks for answering! Yes, I could do this things but how? The only role level that allowed showing the plugin feature in posts is Admin, and that's exactly what I'd like to avoid.
How can I create such a customized user role that achieves showing plugin features at certain areas such as Posts? Can you give me a tip?

Comment: It's likely that the plugin is using one of WP's built-in capabilities, so you won't be able to create create a custom role that only gets access to the plugin features without also opening other features of WP. My suggestion of using a custom role is only so that you can create one with the minimum required permissions, rather than leaving it to WP's standard role settings. You'll need to start by checking the plugin code to see what exact capability is being tested for plugin access, then add that to your custom role. Adding a single capability should be better than using the Admin role.

Comment: As for removing access to unwanted areas, that's always going to be a bit hacky, since you're trying to override WP and that will change over time. It's not particularly secure, but you could do it quickly by enqueuing admin CSS only for a specific role, and using that to hide some admin features. It gets messy.